# Why is Angular not choosing correct overload for HttpClient.get(...)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to abstract out some HttpClient calls (.get(...) and .post(...)) into a BaseService class since I'm having to duplicate code such as headers and credentials if my services don't inherit from a base class.

In doing this, for some reason my code isn't choosing the generic overload on the get.

The following method call is successfully choosing the correct HttpClient.get(...) overload:

[image]

However, the following is choosing a different overload, and I have no idea how to fix it:

[image]

Is this because I'm declaring the private options field incorrectly? I can't find in the API docs a better/correct way of declaring it so that the correct overload will be chosen successfully. Can someone please help me make my code choose the correct (generic `Observable<T>`) overload for HttpClient.get(...)?

Comment: If you are using a base class just to do this (add headers and credentials), you should take a look at HttpInterceptors

Comment: Don't include images of text. Copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: A downvote for using an image instead of text? I used an image to show the intellisense popup as well as the specific line that was causing the error. Copying and pasting the text in failed to create proper bracket alignment, plus it wouldn't have shown the additional information from intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are declaring options with type `any`.

By doing this, the compiler knows **nothing** about the interface/members of `options`, despite the fact that you instantiate its value with an object made of 2 properties.

Refactor into this:

```
export class Foo {
   private options = {headers: {...}, withCredentials: true};
   ....
}
```

Now the compiler can *infer* the type of `options`, instead of statically reading it.