# Angular HttpClient is selecting the wrong get overload

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem very similar to :
[Why is Angular not choosing correct overload for HttpClient.get(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935277/why-is-angular-not-choosing-correct-overload-for-httpclient-get#)

and this:

[Angular HttpClient return expecting observable<HttpEvent<any> rather than observable<any>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401250/angular-httpclient-return-expecting-observablehttpeventany-rather-than-observ)

but neither of those solutions are working.

My code looks like this:

```
 getTopology(): Observable<Topology> {
    var me = this;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let params = new HttpParams();
    let options = {headers: headers, params: params};
    let url = this.url;
    return this.http.getTyped<Topology>(url, options);
}


 getTyped<T>(
     url: string,
     options: {
         headers: HttpHeaders;
         observe?: 'body';
         params?: HttpParams;
         reportProgress?: boolean;
         responseType?: 'json';
         withCredentials?: boolean;
     },
     signRequest = true
 ): Observable<T> {
     options.headers = options.headers.append(
         'Authorization',
         `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
     );
     return this.http.get<T>(url, options);
 }
```

It is pointing to this get:

```
 get(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<Object>;
```

Instead of this get:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<T>;
```

Any suggestions? Also I am using Angular 6.0.6

Answer (score 3):

It happens when you want to wrap `HttpClient` methods, because you pass options dynamically it can't detect type of options. If you change the line

```
return this.http.get<T>(url, options);
```

to this

```
return this.http.get<T>(url, {
     headers: yourHeaders;
     params: params;
 });
```

it will work. I had the same problem when intended to wrap `HttpClient` methods but then gave up because of this.

Comment: Waste few hours to find your solution works, but do you possibly why this happens? And what if I need to dynamically assign value to 'options'?

Comment: To be  honest I can't simulate the problem now ). Copy pasted `getTyped` method to my project and it points to correct overload. In fact my answer doesn't make sense, because options has correct type defined as parent function's argument.