# Using httpOptions in Angular 7 http.get method changes result type

Tags: angular

I'm somewhat new to Angular. I just want to load some products from an API and then create instances of my class (not just objects 'shaped' to my class). So I have a constructor on my Product class that will copy the incoming values.

Here's my method in the service class, which works fine.

```
getProductList(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<Product[]>(this.productListUrl)
        .pipe(
            map(data => data.map(item => new Product(item))),
            catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

However, I also want to pass a token in the GET request header for authentication. So I'm adding an httpOptions object to the get method call (with an Authorization key/value set in the httpOptions):

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

// http options used for making API calls
private httpOptions: any;

private apiURL = environment.apiURL;
private productListUrl = this.apiURL + '/api/v1/products/';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
        observe: 'events'
    };
}

getProductList(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<Product[]>(this.productListUrl, this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            map(data => data.map(item => new Product(item))),
            catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(res: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error(res.error || res.body.error);
    return observableThrowError(res.error || 'Server error');
}
}
```

But somehow the addition of the httpOptions argument to the get method causes the return type to change, and the compile now complains `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Product[]>'.` and won't compile.

Any thoughts on whether I'm doing this wrong, or how I would change the way I'm using map? Thanks!

Comment: What are the options?? Seems you are changing observe property from body to event.

Comment: Add your httpOptions setter

Comment: Check if your `httpOptions` contain `observe: "events"` instead of `observe: "body"`. I think what you want is `observe: "body"`.

Comment: Thanks for comments! I've added my httpOptions declaration to my original question above .  I tried adding `observe:'events'` to my httpOptions but still getting compile error `ERROR in src/app/service/product.service.ts(30,34): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Product[]>'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'HttpProgressEvent'.`

Comment: @DanielMcQ I'm sorry, I meant `observe: "events"` is probably the problem. You should use `observe: "body"`

Comment: Thanks @fridoo. I tried changing above code to have `observe: 'body'` but still same error :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient return expecting observable<HttpEvent<any> rather than observable<any>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401250/angular-httpclient-return-expecting-observablehttpeventany-rather-than-observ)

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/48935277/9423231